# Shapiro.test in R giving "all x values are identical"?

Tags: r, plyr

I've been working on getting a table of shapiro-wilkes normality hypothesis test p-values on a data frame of mine. Here is the data frame (named "mdf1") as a [comma-delimeted CSV](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2MwC8Vr-SXnVmFyMHBWZ2Vtc0U/edit?usp=sharing).

Shapiro-Wilkes testing in R requires a sample size greater than 3. In order to subset my data frame (which contains two pertinent factors, "variable", and "Site"), I used the following code:

```
    Z <- as.data.frame(data.table(mdf1)[, list(freq=.N, value=value), by=list(Site,variable)][freq > 3])
```

This resulted in the data frame "Z" which contained all values which belonged to a "Site"*"variable" combination of n greater than 3. Then, I try to pass Z to the `ddply` function to obtain a table of shapiro-wilkes p-values:

```
    norm2 <- ddply(Z, .(Site, variable), summarize, n=length(value), sw=shapiro.test(value)[2])
```

The result of this command is:

`Error in shapiro.test(val) : all 'x' values are identical`

How can that be? Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure but I suppose that you are splitting the dataframe by a variable, and then applying the test on the splitted variables. E.g. the test on all these `c(1,1,....,1)` and `c(2,2,....2)` etc.

Comment: I see how that would be a problem, but in my `shapiro.test` command in the `ddply` package, I clearly input the "value", not a variable or factor. Each value is a different numeric value.

Comment: This last comment put me on the wrong foot: the message `all 'x' values are identical` is a clear indication that all values supplied to shapiro.test are identical. It may not have been the intention that this would happen, but it did happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` variable is string here. But `??shapiro.test(x)` says that `x` is a numeric vector of data values...Missing values are allowed, but the number of non-missing values must be between 3 and 5000. The first two lines of the code are the same as my answer to your [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257961/how-do-you-subset-a-data-frame-in-r-based-on-a-minimum-sample-size/18258059#18258059) question.

So you can use the following code (tested):

```
mydata$inter<-with(mydata,interaction(Site,variable))
mydata1<-mydata[mydata$inter %in% names(which(table(mydata$inter) > 3)), ]  
library(plyr) 
ddply(mydata1, .(inter), summarize, n=length(value),sw=shapiro.test(as.numeric(value))[2])

                inter  n        sw
1  41332.Effluent (N) 18 0.6294289
2  41369.Effluent (N) 18 0.6294289
3  41385.Effluent (N) 10  0.969692
4  41394.Effluent (N) 12 0.5272433
5  41402.Effluent (N) 12 0.4404443
6  41436.Effluent (N) 14 0.6283259
7  41439.Effluent (N)  6  0.484449
8  41450.Effluent (N)  5 0.5012284
9  41452.Effluent (N) 14 0.5331113
10 41457.Effluent (N) 12 0.5272433
11 41458.Effluent (N) 12 0.5272433
12 43635.Effluent (N)  7 0.7437188
13 41332.Effluent (S) 13 0.5331956
14 41369.Effluent (S)  7 0.4869206
15 41379.Effluent (S)  6  0.484449
16 41385.Effluent (S)  7 0.4869206
17 41394.Effluent (S) 12 0.5272433
18 41436.Effluent (S) 14 0.6283259
19 41332.Influent (N) 18 0.6294289
20 41369.Influent (N) 18 0.6294289
21 41385.Influent (N) 10  0.969692
22 41394.Influent (N) 12 0.5272433
23 41402.Influent (N) 12 0.4404443
24 41436.Influent (N) 14 0.6283259
25 41439.Influent (N)  6  0.484449
26 41450.Influent (N)  5 0.5012284
27 41452.Influent (N) 14 0.5331113
28 41457.Influent (N) 12 0.5272433
29 41458.Influent (N) 12 0.5272433
30 43635.Influent (N)  7 0.7437188
31 41332.Influent (S) 13 0.5331956
32 41369.Influent (S)  7 0.4869206
33 41379.Influent (S)  6  0.484449
34 41385.Influent (S)  7 0.4869206
35 41394.Influent (S) 12 0.5272433
36 41402.Influent (S) 12 0.4404443
37 41436.Influent (S) 14 0.6283259
38 41452.Influent (S)  7 0.6578695
39 41457.Influent (S)  7 0.6578695
40 41458.Influent (S)  8 0.7159932
41         41332.PLot  6  0.484449
42         41369.PLot  6  0.484449
43         41379.PLot  6  0.484449
44         41385.PLot  7 0.4869206
45         41394.PLot 12 0.5272433
46         41402.PLot 12 0.4404443
47         41452.PLot  7 0.6578695
48         41457.PLot  7 0.6578695
49         41458.PLot  8 0.7159932
```

Comment: Assume that I've already run a `as.numeric` function on `Z$value`. How can `shapiro.test` still output that error?  Also, shapiro-wilkes tests should not be run on the "n" value of the sample, but the sample values themselves, so I'm a little confused by your `shapiro.test(n)[2]` syntax.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but you need to implement your assumption in the code which I updated now. It works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just ran that again and got the same error message. Here's my cut and pasted code:`norm2 <- ddply(Z, .(Site, variable), summarize, n=length(value), sw=shapiro.test(as.numeric(value))[2])`

Comment: Please check my updated full code.It should be fine now. Try restarting the `R` if it doesn't.

Comment: Wow, going line-by-line and applying it to R-studio, I still get the same error message, even after restarting. The funny thing is, that when I use ddply and shapiro-wilkes, andersen-darling, and lilliefors tests (on raw, log, and square root-transformed data), it works perfectly: [code](http://imgur.com/cpuKSye) and [printed dataframe](http://imgur.com/bMftSjC). Your example, thus, should work for me since you've reduced the factorization to one variable ("inter"). So strange...

Comment: What I meant above, is that it worked for me using just one factor "(.variable)", which means, once you simplified the data to one factor called "inter", it should also work. However, it does not for whatever reason.

Comment: If I don't have to subset, I won't create that one variable. I have problem using `ddply` for subsetting.

Comment: I figured out the answer. Of the many possible `inter` combinations, there are 7 that have identical values (with which I proved with standard deviations equal to zero). Once I delete these rows and re-run shapiro-wilkes, I should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is as simple as it sounds. Generally, if all values in a column/variable are identical then it means that you will definitely get the error. I would suggest that you first check for and remove variables that have zero variance. This is what has worked for me:

```
# Load dplyr
library(dplyr) # Data manipulation
library(caret) # nearZeroVar function

# Load your data and assign it the name, df
# *code to load data goes here*

# Etract names for numeric columns
numeric_vars<-df%>%select_if(is.numeric)%>%names()

# Extract zero variance variables first
zero_var_columns<-nearZeroVar(df, saveMetrics = TRUE)%>%
filter(zeroVar==TRUE)%>%
row.names()

# Show
zero_var_columns

# Drop zero variance columns
df<-df%>%
select(-zero_var_columns)

# Now test for normality
df%>%
select_if(is.numeric)%>%
sapply(shapiro.test)%>%
t()%>%
data.frame()%>%
select(p.value)%>%
mutate(Is_normally_distributed=p.value>=.05)
```